# Angular - load data at app start and use in controller in different module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, factory

I'm pretty new with Angular and I'm stuck on this for a few days now :(
I have a web app (kind of portal with several web tools available).
I want to load some data from DB when the app being initially accessed and use the data in some controller (.i.e. load the data **only once**).

This is what I have by now:

Main app

```
 var myApp= angular.module('MyApp',['ngRoute','ngTable','mpcApp','registerApp','forgotPasswordApp','tool1App','loginApp','userManagementApp','init']);

 myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/...', {
      templateUrl: 'js/....html',
      controller: 'tool1Ctrl'
    })....
```

I also have myApp.run - but I will describe it later.

I've created different module for my factory:

```
    (function (angular) {    

    var initApp = angular.module('init',[]);

    initApp.factory('EndPoints', ['$http', function($http) {
        var EndPointsList="";
        return{
            getList: function(){
                $http.post("/getEndPoints", {
                    transformRequest : angular.identity,
                    headers : {'Content-Type' : undefined}
                }).

                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {               
                EndPointsList = data;
                    console.log(EndPointsList);
                    return EndPointsList;

                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Failed to load end-points list");                      

                                });
                return EndPointsList;
            }
        };

    }]);
})(angular);
```

What I did next is injecting this factory into myApp.run:

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'SessionIdService','EndPoints', function($rootScope, $location, SessionIdService,EndPoints) {

    $rootScope.EndPoint= EndPoints.getList();
    console.log("Current end-point: " + $rootScope.appEnv);
...
```

This is just not working! I don't see the print in console at all, and when I try to use the $scope.EndPoint in another controller in another module it appears to be empty.

Controller code:

```
    var Tool1Controllers= angular.module('tool1App',[]);
    Tool1Controllers.controller('toolCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$rootScope', function ($scope, $http,$rootScope) {

console.log("Test: Controller end-point: " + $scope.EndPoint);
```

Please help! :(

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `ui-router` and using the `resolve` feature. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: You are returning an empty string in `EndPoints` since you aren't 1) returning a promise and 2) waiting for the promise to resolve.

Comment: @Shaohao Lin - thanks, trying to read about it and understand how exactly it works.

Comment: @lux - yes, you are correct. Trying to resolve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are returning a string before $http promise is fulfilled. You need to wait for the http response before returning data, or return the promise and let the consumers implement the outcome handlers.

Try updating your `factory` as follows:

```
initApp.factory('EndPoints', ['$http', function($http) {
    return{
        getList: function(){
            return $http.post("/getEndPoints", {
                transformRequest : angular.identity,
                headers : {'Content-Type' : undefined}
            });
        }
    };

}]);
```

And your `run` assignment as:

```
EndPoints.getList()
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {               
        $rootScope.EndPoint= data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Failed to load end-points list");                      
    });
```

---

UPDATE: An alternative to attaching data to the $rootScope is to have the factory cache the data and offer a method to return the data either from cache or from the remote endpoint if it hasn't already been cached:

```
initApp.factory('EndPoints', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var endpoints = null;

    return{
        getList: function() {
            return endpoints ?
                // if data is already cached, return it
                $q(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(endpoints); }) :
                // otherwise fetch it from the service, cache it and return it
                $http.post("/getEndPoints", {
                    transformRequest : angular.identity,
                    headers : {'Content-Type' : undefined}
                }).then(function(data) { endpoints = data; return data; });
        }
    };

}]);
```

And now in your controllers, you can just inject the service and define outcome handlers for the getList promise:

```
.controller ...

EndPoints.getList()
    .then(function(data) {               
        $scope.someVariable = data;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Failed to load end-points list");                      
    });

...
```

Since factories are singletons, you can inject the Endpoints service into any number of controllers and the same cached data should be returned so that at most 1 call to the remote endpoint is made.

Comment: thanks for this! Now I actually get a result in .run, but for some reason I can't get the value in the controller. I assumed that if I put the data in $rootScope.EndPoint, I'll be able to access it in ever other modul by using &scope.EndPoint, but it is still undefined. I guess the RUN part happens after the contoller is resolved. Maybe I have to define RESOLVE in $routeProvider? I can't figure out how to do it?..

Comment: I would actually recommend not attaching data to the $rootScope unless you really need to. In your case, I would instead just cache the data in the factory and expose a method that either retrieves it from the cache, if available or pulls it from the getEndpoints service. I will update my answer to show this.

Comment: The thing is that this controller responsible for a view with a drop down list. I have to have the list of end points ready before the view is up, so that the dropdown list will be filled. Does it make sense? I just tried your suggestion and it doesn't seem to be working :( Sorry, for so many questions and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I understand. The angular way to solve that issue, as @Shaohao Lin already pointed out is to resolve your data dependencies in your route so that when your controller is instantiated, it is guaranteed to have the data available. I am a ui-router user, so I can show an example of how to do it if you are also using ui-router.

Comment: I'm not, but I will be, if this what will make this whole thing work:))) Please show me :)

Comment: OMG - just made it work! used the resolve in $routeProvider. Thanks a lot!!!! @GPicazo